# Factorization of vectors $(Z^T Z)^n Z^T-(X^T X)^n X^T$

Tags: matrices, vectors, factoring, matrix-calculus

Is there a way to factorize expression $(Z^T Z)^k Z^T-(X^T X)^k X^T$ where $Z$ and $X$ are real column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that 
\begin{align}
(Z^T Z)^k Z^T-(X^T X)^k X^T=   (Z-X)^T P(Z,X)
\end{align}
where $P(Z,X)$ is a polynomial.

My question is motivated by the following difference formula for real $a$ and $b$
\begin{align}
a^k-b^k= (a-b) P(a,b)
\end{align}
where $P(a,b)= \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a^i b^{k-1-i}$

Comment: What's the value of a polynomial when the variable is replaced by a *vector*? Also, bear in mind $X^TX$ and $Z^TZ$ are real numbers. Thus, you have on LHS a linear combination of $X^T$ and $Z^T$, (which may have an arbitrary direction in a plane if $X$ and $Z$ are not collinear), which you would prove equal to a scalar multiple of $(Z-X)^T$, thus in a fixed direction. Unlikely to work.

Comment: Yes, but $P(Z,X)$ can be real too.

Comment: But the RHS will be collinear to $(X-Z)^T$. However, the LHS is only collinear to $(X-Z)^T$ if further conditions are satisfied.

Comment: What would $P(Z,X)$ be allowed to be? A polynomial in what way?

Comment: Ok. I see. I think I agree with what you are saying.  Can we relax the assumption that $P(Z,X)$ is  a polynomial and stil achieve that form of factorization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\lVert X\lVert=\lVert Z\lVert=a$, then your factorization holds trivially, with $P=a^{2k}$.

If $X$ and $Z$ are not collinear, then let $\lVert X\lVert=a$ and $\lVert Z\lVert=b$, with $a>0,b>0$.

Suppose further that $(Z^T Z)^k Z^T-(X^T X)^k X^T=c(Z-X)^T$ for some real number $c$.

That is, $b^{2k}Z^T-a^{2k}X^T=cZ^T-cX^T$

Since $X$ and $Z$ are not collinear, coordinates along $X^T$ and $Z^T$ of the above linear combination are respectively equal.

Hence, $c=a^{2k}=b^{2k}$.

Therefore, if $X$ and $Z$ are not collinear, your factorization holds iff $\lVert X\lVert=\lVert Z\lVert$.

Comment: When you say $\| X \|$ do you mean $ \sqrt{X^T X}$ ??

Comment: @Boby Yes. And I also suppose $n\geq2$ and $P$ is not necessarily a polynomial in $X$ and $Z$ (that would make no sense anyway), but an arbitrary real-valued function of $X$ and $Z$.

Comment: So, let me re-phrase the factorization $(X^TX)^k X -(Z^TZ)^kZ= (Z-X)^T P(X,Z)$ where $P(X,Z) \in \mathbb{R}$ is an arbitrarry function is possible iff $\|X \| =\| Z\|$. Is this correct?

Comment: If $X$ and $Z$ are not collinear, yes. If they are collinear, it's still possible to find such a factorization, but it's easy to check.